# Push navigation from current context

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Hi i have two Viewcontroller **A** and **B** and i am presenting **B** Controller from **A** Controller with **Current Context** and I pasted my coding below. All i want to push from **B** controller to **C** controller, I know that no navigation controller allocated when we present and if i present navigationcontroller with rootviewcontroller i cannot achieve transparent result.

```
 UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        ChooseAddressVc *sec=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseAddressVc"];
        sec.myDelegate = self;
        sec.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
        sec.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentViewController:sec animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
```

**Pushing from Viewcontroller B to C**

```
UIStoryboard*Story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main2" bundle:nil];
    AddNewAddressVc*choose=[Story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNewAddressVc"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:choose animated:YES];
```

**Note:I need to push from B to C controller when i present with current context.** **FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING**:**WE CANNOT ALLOCATE NAVIGATION CONTROLLER AS ROOT VIEWCONTROLLER FOR A WHEN WE NEED TO GET TRANSPARENCY EFFECT**

Comment: What error/issue are you encountering?

Comment: @JacobBoyd when i present viewcontroller B with current context,I cannot push from viewcontroller b to c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `self.navigationController` in B view controller is nil. You need to create `UINavigationController` with B view controller as `rootViewController`. Present created `UINavigationController` from A instead presenting B view controller, after this you're able to use `self.navigationController` in B view controller.

Your code edited:

```
    UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    ChooseAddressVc *sec=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseAddressVc"];
    sec.myDelegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sec];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
```

Comment: Thats what i mentioned in my comment , i know how to create navigationcontroller with rootviewcontroller while presenting, but if i did that i am getting blackscreen and i cant achieve desired effect with transparency.Please read my question again for better understanding.

Comment: I will try this and let you know asap